# symfony3 doctrine. Make condition for related records

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have entity ShopGoods with relation manyToMany to entity ShopCategory. That's my method for get list of goods:

```
public function getListByFilter(ShopGoodsFilter $filter) {
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('goods')
   ->select('goods')
   ->leftJoin('goods.categories', 'categories')
   ->where('categories.id = :category_id')
   ->andWhere('goods.status=1')
   ->andWhere('categories.status != 0') // it's my try...
   ->setParameter('category_id', $filter->getCategory()->getId())
   ->setMaxResults($filter->getLimit())
   ->setFirstResult($filter->getOffset());
   return [
      'data' => $qb->getQuery()->getResult(),
      'total' => $this->getTotalByFilter($filter)
   ];
}
```

I can't understand how make condition to get goods with `categories.status = 1` for all related categories.

Comment: Looks ok to me, can you post the generated SQL?

Comment: Looks okay to me as well

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('goods')
    ->select('goods')
    ->leftJoin('goods.categories', 'categories', 'WITH', 'categories.status = 1')
```